# Retrieve the distinct items by comparing count

Tags: c#, linq

```
int itemCount=3;

prod.Add("P1");
prod.Add("P2");
prod.Add("P1");
prod.Add("P2");
prod.Add("P1");
prod.Add("P3");
```

In this prod list I want to get count of each item and if the count matches the `itemCount` then need to put it in an array.

In this case only P1 must be put to array.

Can anyone help me out? I want code in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `prod` is a `IEnumerable<string>`, you can do this with linq

```
var results =
    (from s in prod
     group s by s into g
     where g.Count() == itemCount
     select g.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that `prod` is `List<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>` in general:

```
var items = prod.GroupBy(x => x)
                .Where(g => g.Count() == itemCount)
                .Select(g => g.Key)
                .ToArray();
```